# How to select td inside tfoot with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have this html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Body1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I tried to get the `Inner.Html` of the `<td></td>` within `<tfoot></tfoot>`, but I have problem with it.
Here is what I have tried:

```
var mainGrid = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
var footerGrid = mainGrid.SelectSingleNode("//tfoot");
var tdFooterGrid = footerGrid.SelectSingleNode("//td");
if (tdFooterGrid != null)
{
    var a = tdFooterGrid.InnerHtml;
}
```

That was fine until I retrieved the `footerGrid`. When I continued to get the `td` in order to get the `Footer` text, it resulted the `Body 1` instead.

Is there any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below Code will work if you want values inside footer td tag.

```
var footerGrid = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tfoot//td");
if (footerGrid != null)
        {
            var a = footerGrid.InnerText;
        }
```